# Using two GPU video cards

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, performance

Does anyone know, how can I check if I am using my two video cards?

It seem Blender is using only one of them. I have checked both on the user preferences settings. But reading temperatures in GPU-Z it seems Blender is using only one of them.

The first card card is Titan X maxwel and the other is GtX1080 TI pascal.

Please give guidance, I bought this new 1080Ti to speed up the render but is not helping much.

Comment: Please show an image of the System Preferences>System that show what you have for compute device.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to tell if it's using both cards is if you see two tiles being processed simultaneously when rendering.  I have three cards processing this scene and you can clearly see the little orange corners on each of the tiles:

[image]

Also, I'm sure you already know this, but in addition to checking the User Preferences, make sure you have GPU rendering enabled in the Properties Pane:

[image]

Comment: Thanks,,,, i think it was a bug or something weird... I turn it off and then on and it works..

Comment: @Felipe - Hey no problem at all... if this answers your question please accept it so that it moves out of the queue, thanks.